# Use __init_subclass__ to patch abstract methods while preserving the abc check

Tags: python, abc

I would like to wrap an `abstractmethod` for all subclasses of an abc. I tried doing that by implementing `__init_subclass__` as below:

```py
import abc


class Base(abc.ABC):

  @abc.abstractmethod
  def foo(self) -> str:
    pass

  def __init_subclass__(cls):
    super().__init_subclass__()
    orig_foo = cls.foo
    cls.foo = lambda s: orig_foo(s) + 'def'


class Derived(Base):

  def foo(self):
    return 'abc'
```

This works and if I do something like:

```py
derived = Derived()
derived.foo()  # -> 'abcdef'
```

which is expected. Unfortunately, I noticed that this approach does not invoke the abc check, so if I forget to implement `foo` on `Derived`:

```py
class Derived(Base):
  pass
```

I can still create it:

```
derived = Derived()  # This works
derived.foo()        # -> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'NoneType' and 'str'
```

Is there a way to do the above wrapping, but not break `abc.abstractmethod` checks?

Comment: A None check on  `orig_foo` ?

Comment: Seems like orig_foo is not None, but evaluates to `Base.foo` if we forget to implement it in `Derived`. Just posted an answer that addresses it. Thanks for the lead!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it by overriding `cls.foo` in `__init_subclass__` **only if** `cls.foo` differs from `Base.foo` (i.e. is already overridden).

This yields the following `Base` implementation:

```py
class Base(abc.ABC):

  @abc.abstractmethod
  def foo(self) -> str:
    pass

  def __init_subclass__(cls):
    super().__init_subclass__()
    orig_foo = cls.foo
    if orig_foo != Base.foo:  # Already overridden.
      cls.foo = lambda s: orig_foo(s) + 'def'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a better techinque would be to declare a separate non-abstract method that makes use of the abstract method.

import abc

```
class Base(abc.ABC):

  @abc.abstractmethod
  def foo_body(self) -> str:
      pass

  def foo(self) -> str:
    return self.foo_body() + 'def'


class Derived(Base):

  def foo_body(self):
    return 'abc'
```

Concrete subclasses are only responsible for overriding `foo_body`; `Base.foo` itself need not be touched.

Comment: Definitely agree that this is cleaner. For whatever reason, I am trying to do this wrapping to improve efficiency of an existing library, so this would be a breaking change.